# Jquery : find previous element from element with specific class on lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find this element :

```
<ul id="pagin">
  <li><a id="previous">&lt;</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">1</a></li>
  ===> <li><a class="pagination">2</a></li> 
  <li><a class="pagination current">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Current class is changing but I always need to select its previous element if it exists

I tried :

```
$("#pagin li a").closest(".current").prev(".pagination")
$("#pagin li a.current").prev()
$("#pagin li a.pagination.current").prev()
```

Maybe this don't work because it's searching for previous element with .pagination but can't find the way to select the good element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to get `<li>` having `a.pagination.current` element then use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get its  immediately preceding sibling

```
var prevli = $("#pagin li:has(a.pagination.current)").prev();
var prevLiAnchor = prevli.find('a');
```

```js
$("#pagin li:has(a.pagination.current)").prev().css('color', 'red')
```

```css
.current{ color : green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pagin">
  <li><a id="previous">&lt;</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">2</a></li> 
  <li><a class="pagination current">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` and `prev`.

```js
console.log($("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev('li').find('a').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pagin">
  <li><a id="previous">&lt;</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">1</a></li>
  ===> <li><a class="pagination">2</a></li> 
  <li><a class="pagination current">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $("#pagin li").click(function(){
    $("#pagin .pagination").removeClass("current previous");
    $(this).find("a").addClass("current");
    $(this).prev().find("a").addClass("previous");
  });

})
```

```css
.current::after{
  content: " - current";
  color: blue;
}
.previous::after{
  content: " - previous";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on each item</h4>
<ul id="pagin">
  <li><a class="pagination">&lt;</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination previous">2</a></li> 
  <li><a class="pagination current">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">4</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">5</a></li>
  <li><a class="pagination">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousLink = $("ul#pagin li a.current").closest('li').prev().find('a.pagination');

if(previousLink){
  //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

closest is a better way to go because even if you wrap anchor tag(a) with some wrapper for styling, closest will still be able to find the LI tag.

> closest begins with the current element and travels up the DOM tree
>   until it finds a match for the supplied selector.